# Make two buttons the same width as the longest one

Tags: css

`<a class="btn--primary" href="#">Quick simulation</a>`
 `<a class="btn--primary" href="#">New patient</a>`

```
.btn--primary {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding:0 1em;
  text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
  height:50px;
  width: auto;
}
```

I have two buttons one on top of the other, and I want them to have the same width as the one with the longest text in this case "Quick simulation", but without setting a fixed width because there are translations. I want the longest button to only be the width of the text within too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your button are on top of onw another you can wrap buttons with `div` and have `inline-flex` and direction `column` to maintain equal sizes for button

```css
.wrapper{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.btn--primary {
  display: block;
  padding:0 1em;
  text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
  height:50px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="btn--primary" href="#">Quick simulation lorem ipsum dor emit</a>  <a class="btn--primary" href="#">New patient</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the parent to `display: inline-flex` and `flex-direction: column` you'll get the stacking effect and everything will have the same width.

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Short</button>
  <button>Longer button</button>
  <button>A much longer button</button>
</div>
```